# UIPickerView throws -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds when data source is not empty in iOS 8

Tags: xcode, ios8, uipickerview

We have an app which works without any issues in iOS 7, but when running on iOS 8 it crashes with the following error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -       [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

    *** First throw call stack:

    (

 0   CoreFoundation                      0x03361df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182

 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x026fca97 objc_exception_throw + 44

 2   CoreFoundation                      0x03238073 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 243

 3   eAlth Devel                         0x0022f13e -[NSArray(TKCategory) firstObject] + 62

 4   UIKit                               0x00f411ee -[UITableView reloadData] + 443

 5   UIKit                               0x00f45ede -[UITableView _reloadDataIfNeeded] + 78

 6   UIKit                               0x00f4bec7 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 36

 7   UIKit                               0x00ec19c0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 608

 8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02712771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70

 9   QuartzCore                          0x0055a27f -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152

 10  QuartzCore                          0x0054e105 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 397

 11  QuartzCore                          0x0054df60 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26

 12  QuartzCore                          0x004ac676 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284

 13  QuartzCore                          0x004ada3c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392

 14  QuartzCore                          0x004ae108 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92

 15  CoreFoundation                      0x03284fbe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30

 16  CoreFoundation                      0x03284f00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400

 17  CoreFoundation                      0x0327a93a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226

 18  CoreFoundation                      0x0327a1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443

 19  CoreFoundation                      0x03279fdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

 20  GraphicsServices                    0x04aa924f GSEventRunModal + 192

 21  GraphicsServices                    0x04aa908c GSEventRun + 104

 22  UIKit                               0x00e36e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526

 23  eAlth Devel                         0x000f1c5c main + 76

 24  libdyld.dylib                       0x02a53ac9 start + 1

 25  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1

  )

   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The method which was called before the error is:

```
   - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row       forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

        NSObject * sel = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];

        return sel.description;

    }
```

pickerData array object is not nil and it has following objects in it:

```
    self->pickerData:

     <__NSArrayM 0x7c130080>(

    All,

    Br Clinic,

    Clinic 2,

    EssHth,

    GC Clinic,

    HHolistics,

    K5003 - HHD3112,

    K5003 - HHD3112 - Gp2,

    NEW DEMO CLINIC,

    Nursing Home Visits,

    PR Accupuncture,

    PP,

    RB Therapy,

    SC Clinic,

    S Clinic,

    TW Practice

    )
```

Any suggessions on how to fix the issue ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: The array you were attempting to index *was* empty.  If you NSLog it just before you attempt the index op you will see that.

Comment: It is clear that you did not read the answer I have written !
Only thing I change in my code is mentioned in the answer !

Comment: Then it's clear that the problem did not occur when you stepped over the statement you were calling out.

Comment: How am I suppose to put a break point to where I don't have the source code ?

Comment: You had that method, apparently.  How did you know it was being called?

Comment: I did not know this was the method gets called it was added to the project as static library ! Thanks to the expert who pointed it to me, I know it now !

Comment: You said "The method which was called before the error is:", and gave your `titleForRow` method, implying the error was originating there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the following line of my question.

```
3   eAlth Devel                         0x0022f13e -[NSArray(TKCategory) firstObject] + 62
```

In iOS 8 apple has implemented the method for

```
- (id)firstObject
```

But one of the libraries which I used in my project is implementing a Category for NSArray with the above method. The library which I was using was TapkuLibrary.

When initiating the UIPickerView, iOS gets confused about which "firstObject" method to be used. Is it from the core libraries or the one from the TapkuLibrary.

Due to that app crashes.

Exceptions was not clear for me to figure it out. An expert pointed me in the right direction after he so the exception. (Thank you expert ! you save me three more days of head scratching !)

Any how if you are getting a similar exception in iOS 8, check whether you have a "Category" for NSArray.

Remedy is remove the category from your project if it only implements "firstObject" method.
Hope this helps.